# Braintree Error handeling with ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, braintree-sandbox

Hey Everyone I am trying to handel braintree errors but have run into a bit of trouble... I have a vuejs app that makes an ajax call to a php page to create the card.It returns a json object that looks like so:

`{"errors":{},"params":{"creditCard":{"customerId":"885008723","cardholderName":"Holy Sam","expirationMonth":"01","expirationYear":"20","options":{"verifyCard":"true"}},"merchantId":"ygpmj36rrztwbw6x"},"message":"Credit card type is not accepted by this merchant account.\nCredit card number is invalid.","creditCardVerification":null,"transaction":null,"subscription":null,"merchantAccount":null,"verification":null}`

As you can see it gives me an error message but no error code of any kind. How do I get braintree error codes in the response object? Why is it that the errors array is empty yet I am still getting a message? Also does braintree verify the expiration date to make sure its a valid card and if so how would I handle that as I didn't see an error code for it.

Heres the code I am using on the php page:

```
    <?php
  date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
  $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json = json_decode($request_body);

  require_once 'lib/Braintree.php';

  $gateway = new Braintree_Gateway([
    'environment' => 'sandbox',
    'merchantId' => 'key',
    'publicKey' => 'key',
    'privateKey' => 'key'
  ]);

  $result = $gateway->creditCard()->create([
    'customerId' => $json->customerId,
    'cardholderName' => $json->Name,
    'number' => $json->cardNumber,
    'expirationMonth' => $json->Month,
    'expirationYear' => $json->Year,
    'cvv' => $json->Cvv,
    'options' => [
    'verifyCard' => true]
  ]);
  echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

Comment: I would ask braintree support, they have always been helpful to me and quick to respond

Comment: You could also try passing an old expiration date to it to see what the response looks like

Comment: Already tried old date nothing happened